# how to set values in sql when values of one column have to be assigned to individual column based on their id

Tags: sql, oracle

I Have data in one column based on the id I have to determine the value and have to assign it in other columns. How can I do it? Here is the example of my problem.

[image]

and the result that i want is like this

[image]

Comment: can you post expected output ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Remove the tags for the products not involved.)

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server <> Oracle. What are you *actually* using? Please show us your attempts, and explain why they didn't work. Data, as well, is not well receive as an image as it's useless to those you're asking for help from. please supply data as `text`, or even better as DDL and DML statements.

Comment: I am using oracle database.

Comment: How do you identify which value is which measurement as well, I see nothing in your data to denote it.

Comment: *"I am using oracle database."* Then tag that, and *only* that. Why did you tag SQL Server and MySQL, when it isn't what you are using..?

Comment: Is it fixed that height would be 3148 and other columns will have the same values that you have shown in the expected result? If not, then how would you decide which value occurrence will be part of which column e.g. for 5 you have marked it as spine and weight whereas for 6,7,8,9 its marked for height.

Comment: Indeed very strange result.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to find any value for the measurement in your example.

As per your input data, this will be the solution for your expected output.

```
SELECT ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN code = '3148' THEN '3148' ELSE ' ' END) AS Height,
    MAX(CASE WHEN code = '3142' THEN '3142' ELSE ' ' END) AS Width,
    MAX(CASE WHEN code = '3155' THEN '3155' ELSE ' ' END) AS Thickness,
    MAX(CASE WHEN code = '3241' THEN '3241' ELSE ' ' END) AS Spine,
    MAX(CASE WHEN code = '4431' THEN '4431' ELSE ' ' END) AS Weight
FROM Your_table
GROUP BY Id
```